# How to define a key to GET human readable ids in REDIS?

Tags: python, redis, distributed-computing, uniqueidentifier, distributed-system

My goal is to save unique human readable ids in REDIS.

My problem is how to set the **key** to access the value(The value is the generated ID).

If I use an integer, for example, how do I know what is the next integer to GET the data from in redis. And if the application stops, how do I know which integer to return to?

My initial idea was to create all the ids in redis and then use GETDEL because it is O(1). The problem is how to set the key to fetch the generated id.

Comment: "My problem is how to set the key" - and why this is a problem? Could you please add some example, please?

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov Let's assume I have generated 5 IDS. To insert it into REDIS I need to define a value for the key. It is in the format key:value. IDS: {X,Y,Z,K,P}, to put this in redis I need to define a value for the keys of these ids, I can use the same name and it is something like {X:X, Y:Y, Z:Z...} The problem is that I don't know this data before querying. Or I can use an integer and it becomes {1:X, 2:Y, 3:Z...}. My question is how do I define this key thinking about the distribution of the data.

Comment: This sounds like XY problem to me, honestly. If all that matter is values that you generated, just push them into a Redis sorted set (using timestamp as a score, for example), then pop them on demand using ZPOPMAX (or ZPOPMIN depending on the ordering logic), and don't care about keys at all.

Comment: Redis sorted set its O(log(n)) per operation and ZPOPMAX its O(log(N)*M) per operation. 

I cant put a human unique ID inside a redis with O(1) and get with O(1)?

Comment: If the order doesn't matter you can use a simple set and have O(1) for both SADD and SPOP (but the latter will return a random member). Again, your original question focuses a lot on the keys, but it seems to me (but I might be wrong) that keys don't matter to you, only values (that are your "generated human readable IDs" whatever this means) do...

Comment: I may have explained it wrong. The order doesn't matter, my goal is just to get the generated ids. But I don't know what to set in place of the key. How can I fetch the data in O(1) after inserting set("mykey", 'ABCD123') without setting what the mykey is?

Human readable id is an id that you set so that a person can read and remember it easily.

Comment: Redis provides several useful data structures beyond simple SET/GET. I'd suggest reading about [Set](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/sets/) - to me it seems like a possible solution for your use case. Then you add IDs like `SADD 'human_readable_IDs' <id1> <id2>...` and fetch them via `SPOP 'human_readable_IDs'` when necessary (then you have just _one_ key to care about - the set's name itself)...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.